# Moving square with opengl on android

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opengl-es

I have a simple code on OpenGL that moves a square towards the camera using

```
float angle = -10.0f; // Draw frame

void DrawGraphics() {

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Set location in front of camera
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, angle);



glBegin(GL_QUADS);


glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(2.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-2.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

    angle += .1f;

    //if (angle >=360.0f)
            //angle = 0.0f;



// Show the new scene
SwapBuffers(hDC);
}
```

I want to display it on an android system. How do I do that? Should I learn Eclipse and where should I start?

Thank you. I am new to using C++ but I have learned the basics.

Comment: Android is running OpenGL ES, but your code is OpenGL (Desktop), this will not run on Android.

Answer (score 1):

If you're totally new to Android then the first step would be to get the Android SDK set up:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

After that, here are the two introductions to OpenGL ES from the Android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html (more of a crash course)
http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html (more of a tutorial)